# James Bond's identity

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

In Skyfall, there is a distinct scene where Silva has revealed the true identities of several MI6 agents via YouTube, yet there is no hint that Bond's identity is anything of a pseudonym, because we in fact see his parents' gravestone at his former residence.

What makes Bond so special?

Comment: This is really a *suspension of disbelief* issue. Bond's identity is always known...throughout the franchise. For some reason, he rarely uses a name that isn't actually his.

Comment: Also - https://whatwouldbaledo.com/2015/02/24/yes-indeed-james-bond-is-a-codename/

Comment: @Paulie_D Ahh, I've been digging up old history from a few years back!

Answer (score 3):

Part of the Bond mythology is that he was an orphan (family died mountain climbing),  that,  along with his lifestyle means he has nothing to hide,  so doesn't use an alias.

Also his reputation is such that he wants the villain to know who he is to intimidate him.

For example in Casino Royale

> **Le Chiffre:** Mr. Beech, or is that Bond? I’m a little confused.
>
> **Bond:** Well, we wouldn’t want that, would we?

There is also a school of thought that Bond is the **CODE NAME**, and the continuity is maintained across the movies as there have been a number of Bonds over the years, and the name is maintained for MI6's best agent due to the reputation.

This is suggested by quotes (Lazenby saying "**this never happened to the other guy**") and by actions (Brosnan Bond is left with Jinx and a big box of diamonds, but is not contacted by M in the usual bedroom embrace.

Also by out-of-time objects:

- The Connery era gadgets in Die Another Day
- The Goldfinger DB5 in Skyfall/Spectre, which has the BMT216A numberplate, so isn't the Casino Royale one.

Comment: I'm not contradicting you here, but could you provide a source for this info?  SE generally encourages answers that are supported (as much as possible) with verifiable sources.

Comment: In one or the Roger Moore films, Bond visits his wife's grave. She was killed by  Blofeld in *In Her Majesty's Secret Service*, when Bond was Lazenby. Also, *Diamonds Are Forever* is a direct sequel to the Lazenby film, as Connery-Bond is hunting Blofeld for revenge.

Comment: Yes, so Connery Bond retires at end of YOLT, Lazenby comes in (doesn't recognize Blofeld), wife dies and is shown racked in grief.  Connery reappears (fatter, hairpiece), chases Blofeld, but then departs with Tiffany Case.  In FYEO, Moore Bond puts flowers on the grave, but isn't too upset, and the whole event turns into a Blofeld trap, where Moore drops him down a chimney, so neither event supports/negates the scenario.

Comment: It's like Licence to Kill, Bond (Dalton) has gone rogue and lost his licence. In the same timeframe Brosnan Bond attacks the Russian facility with Alec Trevelyan (Goldeneye).

Comment: I don't 100% subscribe to it, but you can't reconcile the DAD artifacts or the DB5 in Skyfall/Spectre unless you at least give it a thought.